# Delete commerce line item with Ajax

Tags: craft3, plugin-craftcommerce2

I am attempting to delete a commerce line item with ajax request but nothing ever deletes. Am i doing something wrong? Vue function below:

```
removeLine(id) {

            axios.post('', {
                    [this.csrfName]: this.csrfToken,
                    action: 'commerce/cart/update-cart',
                    lineItems: {[id]: {'remove': true}}
            },
            {
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-Token': this.csrfToken
                },
            }).then(function (response) {

            }).catch(function (error) {
                // handle error
                console.log(error);
            }).finally(function () {
                // always executed
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Issue resolved. Having checked with Yii debug bar i could see that there was no $_post data with the request. It seems axios sends the data as JSON and not usual post data. Switching to vue-resource enabled me to post the data for craft to use, new code:

```
this.$http.post('', {
    [this.csrfName]: this.csrfToken,
    action: 'commerce/cart/update-cart',
    lineItems: {[id]: {'remove': 1}}
}, {
    emulateJSON: true,
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-Token': this.csrfToken
    }
})
```